# nativescript - gradle error when run tns run android

Tags: android, typescript, gradle, nativescript

I am making a nativescript app and when I run tns run android I get this error:

Unable to apply changes on device: FA53YYJ05603. Error is: spawn gradlew.bat ENOENT.

If I do tns build andoid I get this error:

Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

I have tried tns platform remove android and then tns platform add android and still get the error.

I have the gradlew.bat file

I have gradle5.1.1 installed.
I even get this error after creating a new nativescript app.

I am really new to nativescript.

Comment: This helps you? https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1836

Comment: I have the gradlew.bat file in platform/android